# NSURLConnection reuse

Tags: nsurlconnection, afnetworking

Is there a way to configure AFNetworking to reuse one single NSURLConnection for all requests going to the same host (until the connection is explicitly closed or results in an error)?
Or will I have to modify AFURLConnectionOperation myself?

I will be grateful for any hints on this subject. Thanks.

Comment: Why you using AFNetworking you can do it direktly with NSURLConnection.

Answer (score 0):

NSURLConnection manages its own connection pool. Use `Keep-Alive` and HTTP pipelining to increase the reuse of existing connections. Beyond that, there's nothing else to be done without dipping down into the underlying CFNetwork layer.